# Adding Button programatically to GridView - Getting UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: android

Logcat Message:

```
> 11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator/com.example.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:451)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-27 05:33:47.706: E/AndroidRuntime(2417):     ... 11 more
```

Code:
        `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.keys);
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("1");
    gv.addView(b);`
```

I am getting unsupported exception in `gv.addView(b)`

XML-File:`enter code here`

```
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
android:columnOrderPreserved="false"   

android:columnCount="1"
android:rowCount="3"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/resBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:hint="@string/nothing"
    android:gravity="right" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/calBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:hint="@string/zero" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/keys"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="232dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:numColumns="4" 
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:clipChildren="true" />
```

`

Comment: you can not add views to GridView or ListView like that.
use ListAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html to add Views to GridView

Comment: Then, what is the wayout to approach this ? Any Suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridVIew is very similar to a list view, we CANNOT add any item to it by calling addView(), it is unsupported after initial APIs. Instead we should define an adapter and set the gridview to it

"void   addView(View child)
This method is not supported and throws an UnsupportedOperationException when called."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 2):

To add Views to GridView you need to create Adapter and use the same. For more details refer to following example :

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/